# Foreach from explode

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, explode

I found problem with this:

```
    $explode = explode($start, $data);
    $abc = explode($end, $explode[1]);
    $found = $abc[0] . '<br/>';
    $found .= $abc[1] . '<br/>';
    $found .= $abc[2] . '<br/>';

    return $found;
```

The **abc[0]**, **abc[1]** and more is randomly based by exploded results. How to define if **$found** is array or something I can loop it in foreach?

That's. Thank You for answer.

Comment: What are `$start`, `$end` and `$data` defined as?

Comment: Would `is_array()` help?

Comment: And if you need to find a value **in** the **array**, use (you guessed it) `in_array()`!

Comment: Hello @rwacarter, thanks for answer. There is my complete scripts: 


 `function get_download($id)
 {
  $url = 'http://www.example.com/posts/' . $id;
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $start = '<div id="downloadlist" class="downloadlistclass">';
  $end = '</div>';

  $explode = explode($start, $data);
  $results = explode($end, $explode[1]);
  $found = $results[0] . '<br/>';
  $found .= $results[1] . '<br/>';
  $found .= $results[2] . '<br/>';

  return $found;
 }`

Answer (score 2):

`explode($start, $data)` will return an array unless `$start` is an empty string `""` in which case it will return `false`. You can confirm whether `$found` is an array by using `is_array($found)` which will return `true` if `$found` is an array and `false` otherwise.